# Sort Vector of objects in Scala

Tags: sorting, scala

How can I sort a Vector of my objects in Scala? Is there some library sorting routines or do I have to write my own?

I have a class:

```
class Data2D(var x:Int, var y:Int)
```

and I am passing a vector of these to my function:

```
private def foo(data: Vector[Data2D]): Int = {
     data:Vector sortedOnX = // ??
}
```

how can I sort the vector, based on the x-values of the Data2D objects?

In java I do:

```
Collections.sort(data, XComparator.INSTANCE);
```

where XComparator is:

```
enum XComparator implements Comparator<Data2D> {
    INSTANCE;
    @Override
    public int compare(Data2D o1, Data2D o2) {
        if (o1.getX() <= o2.getX()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private def foo(data: Vector[Data2D]): Int = data.sortBy(_.x)
```

See also the methods `sortWith` and `sorted`, as well as the methods provided by the `Ordering` object.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would have never guess to provide "_.x" argument - as my eclipse autocompletion indicates that "sortBy()" takes no parameters.

Comment: @drozzy Weird. Scaladoc is your friend: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html

Comment: Yeah, I find the scaladoc cryptic too :) It's just a lot of parenthesis and square brackets, I'm like o_o   http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html