# How can i sort a Vector of objects in Scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark

I have a Vector of objects of a particular class. How can I sort them? Which comparison method must I add to a class to make it sortable? If not method, which ordering function should I implement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981818/sort-vector-of-objects-in-scala

Answer (score 4):

Method `sorted` of `Vector` takes an implicit parameter of type `math.Ordering[B]`, which it uses for sorting. There are several ways to provide it:

1. Define an implicit `math.Ordering[MyClass]`. You can create an `Ordering` for your class using the methods from the `Ordering` companion object:

   ```
   case class MyClass(field: Int)
   object MyClass {
     implicit val MyClassOrdering: Ordering[MyClass] = Ordering.by(_.field)
   }
   ```

   If the `Ordering` is defined in the companion object of `MyClass`, it'll be provided for sorting automatically. Otherwise, you'll have to import it manually before calling `sorted`. `Ordering` allows to provide several different ordering defined on a class, and to import or provide explicitly the one you want.
2. Have your class extend [`Ordered[MyClass]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/#scala.math.Ordered) by overriding `compare` method. In this case the necessary `Ordering` will be created implicitly.

   ```
   case class MyClass(field: Int) extends Ordered[MyClass] {
     def compare(other: MyClass): Int = this.field compareTo other.field
   }
   ```

   This will also add methods `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` to the class.
3. Use `sortBy` or `sortWith` methods of `Vector`, which take a function and don't need an `Ordering` parameter.

   ```
   vectorOfMyClass.sortBy(_.field)
   vectorOfMyClass.sortWith(_.field < _.field)
   ```